# Bootstrap dropdown menu hiding behind the div

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Fiddle to demonstrate the HTML content: https://jsfiddle.net/ASel1984/dd9gpnot/4/

Here I have bootstrap button which will show drop menu upon click.

When I click my button, the drop menu content is hiding behind the header `div`. How can I show the drop menu items to appear above the header `div`?

Note: I want to show only drop menu items above the header `div`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the class `dropup` from the div like this   `<div class="btn-group  pull-right">`

#### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/dd9gpnot/5/)

Or, if you want it to drop up, you can change the `overflow: auto;` on `.div2` to  `overflow-y: visible;`

#### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/dd9gpnot/7/)